# Which Wi-Fi channel should I use for my Wi-Fi?

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

which channel is the best fit for my Wi-Fi?

I'm the one on channel 7.

[Picture from Inssider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brsXb.jpg)

Comment: Everyone around you is on the worst possible channels. Your choice is effectively between bad, bad, and worse.

Answer (score -1):

I've learned that the faster the connection i.e. 2ghz vs. 5ghz (5 being faster) the 2ghz is able to travel across space easier. The faster signal can easily be disrupted with things in the environment (furniture, walls, etc.) so if it has a Clark path to your device then 5 ghz is better. If there is a lot of interference then the slower speeds are better.
Hope this helps.